# Viewstate JavaScript being appended to end of Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, developer-console

I have a Visualforce page that downloads XML content.

```
<apex:page applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" contentType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" controller="PodKmlController" >
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
      <!-- ... -->
  </Document>
</kml>
</apex:page>
```

It works fine, except recently in testing it has started failing due to the following JavaScript being appended after the page content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    SfdcApp.Visualforce.viewstate.ViewstateSender.sendViewstate('https://ap2.salesforce.com', 'PodKmlExport');
</script>
```

This is invalidating the XML document.

Where is this extra JavaScript coming from?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this was only being appended when using the Developer Console to preview the Visualforce page.

When the developer console opens the page it appends the query string `core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1`. Removing that additional query string removes the offending JavaScript.